# Why is this function executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, control-flow

I need help with understanding how the following script is working.

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log("A");
}

(function() {
    // Empty
})
```

When running this script with node (v5.9.1) **the output is "A"**. I would expect it to just do nothing. Why is *foo* executed here? I can either delete the first or last three lines and then there is no output.

- Edit: it works as expected if I place a `;` after the curly bracket on line 3. But why?

Comment: You probably should put a semicolon on line 3, as your ending your statement. - (This is one reason why you shouldn't rely on ASI people!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put `(...)` immediately after a function expression, you execute that function.

The code in the question defines a function which calls `console.log`. Then it calls that function (passing it an argument (which isn't used) of a function which does nothing anyway). Then it assigns the return value of calling the first function to `foo`.

It could be rewritten as:

```
var function_a = function() {console.log("A");};
var function_b = function() {};
var foo = function_a(function_b);
```

… with the only side effects being the creation of the `function_a` and `function_b` variables.

---

Semi-colon insertion is usually considered harmful because it leads people to expect whitespace to separate the statement into two unrelated expressions.

JSHint would warn you of the problem:

> 7 Missing semicolon.

Comment: What is the difference between `(function(){ ... })()` and `function(){ ... }()` then?

Comment: @JAyP `function(){}()` is not a valid syntax if used alone. It works in your case since `var foo = ...` makes it into an expression.

Comment: @JAyP — Depends on what appears to the left hand side of the expression. If there is something else that would make the second statement a function expression, then absolutely nothing of practical effect.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript interprets `(...)` as a call to the previously defined function (note that you pass another function as an argument, which is ignored in `foo`) since there is nothing between `}` and `(` symbols.

Answer (score 1):

With your code

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log("A");
}

(function() {
    // Empty
})
```

the javascript interpreter is reading this :

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log("A");
}(function() {});
```

For the interpreter you declared an anonymous function, and pass it a parameter and it returns nothing, then value of foo is `undefined`

That's why it is very important to put `;` in each end of line when it is neccessary.